# power supply independent biasing

Tags: current-mirror

In the current mirror given below

[image]

I can see that the Iref produced strongly depends on Vdd whihc is the supply.

In the diag shown below which is power supply independent as they call it,
[image]
I do not understand how this is power supply independent. The PMOS M3 and M4 anre supply dependent as M3 is purely a diode connected transistor and it strongly depends on the supply. So my question is what makes this set up power supply independent or in other words less sensitive to the power supply ?

Comment: I think you are right. In the cases you have included, the bias current depends on VDD. If VDD is not regulated, the bias current will be variable. Biasing always requires some type of reference. If you don't have a regulated rail, I think a diode connected FET can serve as a reference. In discrete designs, a chain of diodes can be used as  reference, or you can use a Vbe multiplier if you want to use Vbe as a reference. These are crude references. Good analog IC designers can probably do much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This current supply is independent of the Voltage because the voltage source isn't the reference for the resistance.

It's a bit easier if you walk through how this stabilizes itself. When Vdd is applied a reference current is forced on M1 because it is diode tied. This reference current gets multiplied by ~K in M2 and that current flows into the resistor which produces a voltage. That Voltage takes away the amount of voltage available for the PMOS M3 mirror. That in turn forces the PMOS M4 to reduce the reference current to M1, so M2 produces less current  which lowers the Voltage drop across R increasing the amount of voltage for M3 and this keeps going until it stabilizes.

As you can see in this example. I never once needed to know what Vdd was. So long as Vdd was low enough that it doesn't harm the mosfets, then the mosfets regulate themselves using the voltage feedback from a known resistor. That's why this is "supply independent (within reason)."

Comment: Sure now I get it ! Just need to get clarified on this part alone, as the current flows to the resistor the voltage at the drain of PMOS M3 increases ! And since it is diode connected, the gate voltage also increases but the Vsg decreases now. Since the Vsg has decreased the PMOS's conduct less and then due to this current decreases and the voltage drop at resistor decreases and this continues till it stabilizes.Right ??

Comment: PMOS are opposite of NMOS. So since the Nmos is force to operate based on it's gm/ID and "on resistance" because of the M1 current mirror, the voltage across it is stable. That current through the Nmos then forces a stable voltage on the Resistor. The higher the current, the higher the voltage. Since there's finite amount of voltage from Vdd the Pmos gets whatever is left. However, since there needs to be Iout current through M3 it it needs to have a certain Vgs. Since M3 is diode tied Vgs=Vds. Based on the sizing, there will not be enough voltage. So the current mirrored in M4 is lowered.

Comment: Perfect ! Now I understand it clearly ! Why is a start up circuit needed for this setup is it because during startup it takes a lon time for this setup to kick in so in order to reduce this time duration we have a start up whihc kicks in the process much earlier than with out it , is it ??

Comment: Start up circuit forces the solution we care about. Truth is there are two valid solutions to this current problem. 0 and X, where X is based on the sizing and the resistance. Start up is there to force the answer to **NOT** be the zero answer. (I just assumed you had that, my bad.)

Answer (score 0):

The above circuit may have a start up problem if all the transistors have a zero current. When the supply is turned on the transistors may remain in the same state. So to overcome this state we need to introduce a diode connected mosfet so when supply is turned on the diode connected mosfet turns on and it provides the current path from VDD through M3 and M1 to the ground. Hence it reduces the start up time

Comment: Why don't you draw a schematic to explain how to connect the diode?

Answer (score 0):

Vdd increase----> Iout Increase------> the (Iout*Rs ) increases-----> Decreasing the Vgs of M2----> ad hence the Current through the M2 decrease... do the simulation in cadence u ll know